# Different ways to see if a row was returned in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm not sure if there's a question similar because i'm not sure what to search for but anyway.

After I do a query (that has 1 table), there are two ways which I check to see if a row was returned, either:

```
$a = $members->prepare("select userid from users where userid = ?");
$a->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['token']);
$a->execute();
$a->store_result();
if ($a->num_rows == 1) {
    // do something
}
```

or:

```
$b = $members->prepare("select userid from users where userid = ?");
$b->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['token']);
$b->execute();
$b->bind_result($uid);
$b->fetch();
if (isset($uid)) {
    // do something
}
```

Which one is best to use to see if a row was returned? I thought that because num_rows is there for that purpose then it should be used, but you have to store the result set, so i'm not sure, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is probably the best. By the way, from php.net:

> mysqli_store_result() returns FALSE in case the query didn't return a
>   result set

and

> This function also returns FALSE if the reading of the result set failed.

So you could also say:

```
if ($a->store_result()) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add LIMIT 0,1 to the sql query and you can use the one you prefer.
But I prefer the first one.